# Conditional if else statement

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
prices = [80, 102, 84, 41, 74, 55, 32, 77, 92, 40, 91, 26]
wealth = 5000
init_price = 100
buy = []
sell = []
x = 0

for i, v in enumerate(prices):
    if (v > init_price):
        buy = wealth + 1000
        continue
    else:
        buy_1 = buy.append(buy - 1000)
        continue`
```

I would like to run through the loop and for each time the price is more than initial price I would add 1000 to wealth. For each time the loop is less than initial price I would like to minus 1000 from the wealth. Then I would like to find the final value after all the iteration. Anyone able to help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
In [191]: for price in prices: 
     ...:     if price > init_price: 
     ...:         wealth += 1000 
     ...:     else: 
     ...:         wealth -= 1000 
     ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [192]: wealth                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[192]: -5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the correct version:

```
prices = [80, 102, 84, 41, 74, 55, 32, 77, 92, 40, 91, 26]
wealth = 5000
init_price = 100
sell = []
x = 0

for v in prices:
    if (v > init_price):
        wealth += 1000
    else:
        wealth -= 1000
print(wealth)
```

Result:

```
-5000
```